# Completion Callback in android thread pool

Tags: android, multithreading, callback, threadpool

I have developed an application to read KML files of point type and then update their elevation using [Google Elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/start). As you can see it receives latitude and longitude of the point and appends it with an API key to retrieve the elevation. Because my KML files have multiple points, I've used ThreadPool to read lat and long of points, append it with the key, and send the URL to Google Elevation API.Something like this:

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(CORE_NUMBERS + 1);
    String providerURL = provider.getServiceURL();
    String providerKey =  provider.getServiceAPIkey();

for (PointFeature p: points) {

        String coordinate = p.getLatitude() + "," + p.getLongitude();       // get latitude and longitude of the feature
        String url = providerURL + "locations=" + coordinate + providerKey; // creating the url of web service which contains coordinate
        HeightTask task = new HeightTask(url, p);                           // task of each points            
        executor.execute(task);       
      }
```

The heightTask class is where I parse the JSON result from API and get the elevation and set the heithUpdate flag. Here is the snippet:

```
public class HeightTask implements Runnable {

private String url;    
private Feature feature;

public HeightTask(String url, Feature f) {

    this.feature = f;
    this.url = url;    
}

@Override
public void run() {

    if (feature instanceof PointFeature) {

        float height = GoogleAPIJsonParser.parsePoint(HttpManager.getData(url));
        if (height != Float.NaN){

            feature.updateHeight(height);
            feature.setHeightUpdated(true);
            Log.d("elevationPoint",height+"");
        }
    } 
}
}
```

What I need is a callback to know if the elevation of all points in a layer has been updated. Is there any pattern in threadPool or just loop through all points and check the hieghtUpdate flags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify code as below.

1. Change your `HeightTask` to implement [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) interface.
2. Prepare a collection of Callable tasks and submit using [invokeAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-)

   ```
    List<HeightTask > futureList = new ArrayList<HeightTask >();
    for (PointFeature p: points) {

       String coordinate = p.getLatitude() + "," + p.getLongitude();       // get latitude and longitude of the feature
       String url = providerURL + "locations=" + coordinate + providerKey; // creating the url of web service which contains coordinate
       HeightTask task = new HeightTask(url, p);    
       futureList.add(taks);     
    }
    executor.invokeAll(futureList);
   ```

invokeAll:

```
<T> List<Future<T>> invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks)
                       throws InterruptedException
```

> Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete. Future.isDone() is true for each element of the returned list. Note that a completed task could have terminated either normally or by throwing an exception.